# Cannot deploy to gcloud

Tags: maven, deployment, gcloud

I am trying we deploy a java webservice to gcloud through the gcloud shell, but I get the following error...

```
[INFO] Running python -S /google/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py --quiet preview app deploy /home/jimmy/jimmies-service/target/appengine-staging/app.yaml --promote
[INFO] ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'preview'.
```

Does anyone know how I can change the choice option or why It says 'preview'

Im stumpt...

Cheers in advance

Comment: What plugin are you using for deployment?

Comment: I was following this tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0, <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9.106.v20160420</version>
      </plugin>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an out-of-date `gcloud-maven-plugin`; follow [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-maven-plugin/issues/92) for updates.

You can work around by installing an old version of `gcloud`:

```
$ gcloud components update --version 140.0.0
```

You may not be able to update the default gcloud on Cloud Shell; in that case, please install another copy using [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-linux).

Comment: Hey, big thanks for the response. Its seems to have worked somewhat but now I get [INFO] denied: Unable to create the repository, please check that you have access to do so.
[INFO] ERROR: failed to push because we ran out of retries.